# как могу поставить условие constraint чтобы дата рождения было минимум 18 лет?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, constraints

как могу поставить условие constraint чтобы дата рождения было минимум 18 лет?
заранее благодарю за ответ )

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так

```
ALTER TABLE <your_tablename> ADD CONSTRAINT table_check_birthday CHECK (
    date_part('year', age(birthday_field, current_date) >= 18)
);
```